# Plotting a region in $3D$ space

Tags: graphing-functions, maple, mathematica

I would like to know if someone knows of a software where I can plot the following region

$$ D = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: 0 \leq x \leq 1 , \; x^2 \leq y \leq x, \; \; 0 \leq z \leq x \} $$

thanks

Comment: Mathematica should be able to do that (with `RegionPlot3D`). However given that you tagged your question with [tag:maple] I'm not sure that this answers your actual question (although it answers the question you've written).

Comment: I dont know how to use neither mathematica nor maple :/

Comment: Anyway, I just now notice that you specified a region in 2D ("$(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$") with a parameter $z$. Did you possibly mean "$(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3$"?

Comment: YEs. sorry for the mistake :/.

Comment: Well, maple and mathematica are pretty much the standard tools. Are you asking for help with those programs? The other option is to go full hardcore and program it yourself(which is fun, btw)

Comment: I would like to know if there is an easier way to do it, or if someone can help plot it.

Comment: @chubakueno Saludos! Yo tambien soy de Peru, de que parte eres?

Comment: Hola! Soy de Lima, y tú? Esta es la primera vez que veo un peruano de manera confirmada .También (creo) Atahualpa es de acá, pero no estoy muy seguro. Podrías mover esta discusión al chat? Estoy desde celular y no puedo, te lo agradecería :)

Comment: No tengo idea como mover esta discusion al chat, pero escribeme a lordjym15@gmail.com para conversar. Es tambien la primera vez que veo un Peruano por estos lares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mathematica you get a plot of the region using

```
RegionPlot3D[0 <= x <= 1 && x^2 <= y <= x && 0 <= z <= x,
             {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

The first argument you'll easily identify as your region specification. The following arguments give the variables and the range which should be shown (you generally want the complete region to be inside, but not too much space around it).

Now, this command gives only a quite approximate image of the shape, because it uses too few points. The following gives a much better image:

```
RegionPlot3D[0 <= x <= 1 && x^2 <= y <= x && 0 <= z <= x,
             {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
             PlotPoints->100]
```

The extra argument tells Mathematica to calculate 100 points in each direction, which gives a better image.

Also note that if you only get a black blob (which happens for me with those commands, although it theoretically shouldn't), you'll have to add `PlotStyle->White` to the command, like this:

```
RegionPlot3D[0 <= x <= 1 && x^2 <= y <= x && 0 <= z <= x,
             {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
             PlotPoints->100, PlotStyle->White]
```

Instead of `White` you can use another colour (which is mainly useful if you want to show several regions in the same picture).

Also if you want your axes to be labelled, you can use the `AxesLabel` option, like this:

```
RegionPlot3D[0 <= x <= 1 && x^2 <= y <= x && 0 <= z <= x,
             {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
             PlotPoints->100, PlotStyle->White,
             AxesLabel->{HoldForm[x], HoldForm[y], HoldForm[z]}]
```

The `HoldForm` protects against any assignments you may have done to those variables prior to the statement (otherwise, if you had assigned `x=3` previously, your x axis would be labelled `3` instead of `x`).

The result of the last command looks like this:

[image: Resulting image of previous command]

Note that inside Mathematica, you can interactively rotate that image.

Comment: Instead of the `HoldForm[x]`, I just use `"x"` placed in quote marks, which treats the x as a string. You might have to italicise the `x` too, as per preference.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Mathematica code:

```
RegionPlot3D[
  0 <= x && x <= 1 && x^2 <= y && y <= x && 0 <= z && z <= x,
 {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, PlotPoints -> 35
]
```

and the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Maple this can be done with `plots:-implicitplot3d`, but a sharper result is obtained more easily by simply using the `plot3d` command with its `filled` option.

The upper z-surface is simply z=x, and the lower surface is z=0, and filling between them corresponds to your constraints z>=0 and z<=x.

```
plot3d(x, y = x .. x^2, x = 0 .. 1,
       filled=[color=blue,style=patchnogrid,transparency=0.5]);
```

[image]

If I had used `plots:-implicitplot3d` instead then I would have had to specify *some* ranges explicitly for each of x, y, and z. In the above call to `plot3d` I did not have to deduce in advance (by hand, or by using other commands) or specify in the call to the command that the y-range was 0..1 and that the z-range was 0..1. I was able to avoid that step (and use `plot3d` directly) because the constraints are simple enough. I feel that the distinction is important enough to warrant a mention.